# Not merging a file in Git?

Tags: git

I have three branches of a project, development, testing and production. Each branch needs an xml file, with different contents for each branch. Is there a way of telling git to keep the file around, but when merging branches, ignore that file?

Answer (score 3):

That implies that you don't have just one file, but three. Instead of foo.xml: foo-dev.xml, foo-test.xml, and foo-prod.xml, for example.

Comment: You could also have a single file with three sections rather than three files, but the basic answer here is correct. There's no way to do what the original question describes, so you'll need to handle it another way.

Comment: Another way to handle it would be to have a build procedure to copy over the correct file.

Comment: @Kyralessa: I don't see how that would help with the source control problem of having the same file with different content in three different branches.

Comment: Because you could have three files with three separate names, and the build copies over the correct file and gives it the standard name.  You have foo-dev.xml, foo-test.xml, and foo-prod.xml, and the build copies the right one to foo.xml for the current build configuration.

Comment: Okay, yeah, I agree. That's what I meant. I thought you were suggesting it as an alternative instead of adding information. Sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

You can put your xml file in to your .gitignore file

```
$echo <your xml file> >> .gitignore
```

Your .gitignore should be under your 3 git repository

Comment: If the OP does this then the file won't be in their repository. It sounds like they want it there, just not merged